# Why does the writable part of the form start from the middle?

Tags: html, css, forms

Basically I tried to make a form for the first time, but I can't manage to understand why the writable area doesn't start from the beginning. I think it might have something to do with the padding, but I'm not sure. I know that the answer will probably be obvious, but I'm pretty new to this enviroment and to be honest I can't figure it out. Obviously there isn't all of the code of the website, I just posted the interested part.Thank you in advance.

```css
label{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin-left: -390px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
textarea{
    padding: 12px 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #222326;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    text-align: left;
}
.msg-label{
    margin-left: -345px;
}

.email-label{
    margin-left: -398px;
}

textarea{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding-right: 300px 220px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
```

```html
        <div id="contact-me">
            <div id="center">
                <h2>CONTACT ME</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="center">
                <form action="action-page.php">
                    <label for="name" class="name-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="full-name" >

                    <label for="email" class="email-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">

                    <label for="message" class="msg-label">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="msg" name="message"></textarea>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
textarea{
    padding: 12px 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #222326;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    text-align: left;
}
```

its the padding that you have added in the snippet above. padding adds space within the element as such you are pushing everything inside.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed using width instead of padding.